# TFS: What should I do about checking in the application dll?

Tags: tfs

I work on a site where none of us have used TFS before, but we are now having to do so.
As a result there are some odd issues that I need to sort out.
Where I have an application say APP, when I build my application a new APP.dll is created.
I have found that when I build and deploy my application, I have to check in this into source control on TFS 2010.
That is fine when I am working on this my myself. But how should I manage this when I am working in a team? Everyone will want to compile their own version of APP and will need a different APP.dll as a result.
I am sure there is a simple solution to this. I look forward to finding out what it is.

Comment: "I have to check in this into source control on TFS 2010" --> can you please elaborate on why/how that is necessary? When you say 'build', you mean Ctrl+Shift+B in Visual Studio, right?

Comment: I mean in Team Explorer, I configue a build there.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Do not store your build assemblies (*.dll) in source control, but use the build that is available for you in TFS. The Build system will compile all the sources and drop the created binaries in a folder share. You can use the files in the share to distribute / deploy your application.

You can find more information on the build at http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ms181709.aspx

Comment: I cannot find a way to exlude the DLL from source control. If I exclude the dll from the application, the application does not compile. If I include it in the project, I get a tick letting me know it is locked out for edit.

Comment: When building your application, do you need to have the dll included in your project? Normally you use references to 'include' other assemblies. Those references are not stored in source control.

Comment: When I exclude the dll, my application does not compile.

Comment: What is the error message? When you added the file to source control, the readonly bit is applied to the file. When you exclude it, the readonly bit is not removed. Is that maybe the case for you too? Remove the readonly attribute from the APP.dll and try again. If that is not the solution, please share your error message

Comment: Ah yes, that was the problem! Excellent, thank you very much!